# Windows 10, mamp, composer not installing, but openssl & extension_dir enabled

Tags: php, composer-php, mamp

I have mamp installed and am using windows 10. I have attached an image of the configurations, the error, and some of the things I've done to diagnose why. I don't know why I am continuously getting this composer error. I am updating my php.ini file, which had openssl commented out. I removed the semicolon on extension_dir (was already removed), and on extension=php_openssl.dll. I have noticed that when I type in php -m in my command prompt, I am not seeing open ssl, and I'm not sure how to enable that, if that is the possible issue.

If there can be any light shed on this, let me know, I understand this issue is answered hundreds of times over, but I have done what was required from those answers, and got no where.

Image clarifications: The error

[image: Error]

Here is where I am checking the configurations with php -m and it's not showing openssl, correct me if I'm mistaken.

[image]

My phpinfo(); with also me doing php -ini, it's showing php isn't set, but it is when I run the phpinfo method, i'm assuming because this method is being run through mamp allowing it to set the correct parameters.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that might be my only option at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the command-line PHP loads an ini file somehow. The easiest is probably to copy c:\MAMP\conf\php7.0.0\php.ini to wherever your php.exe is located. To find that out you can use `where php` which should return you the full path to it. Copy the ini file in that directory and it should find it and load the module (although you might have to adjust the extension_dir depending on how it is set).

See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php if you want more details on how the ini file is located.

Answer (score 2):

you only need to copy php.ini from the conf directory to your php directory and it will work fine.

**just** copy php.ini from

`MAMP/conf/php(version of your php)/php.ini`

to

`MAMP/bin/php/php(version of your php)`

then try in command line `php composer.phar install'

Answer (score 1):

for install composer and enable openssl extension, copy your `php.conf` in `MAMP\conf\php{php-version}` for `MAMP\bin\php\php{php-version}` and edit `php.conf` changing `;extension=php_openssl.dll` for `extension=php_openssl.dll`. 
Then try installing normally.

Answer (score 1):

Running Windows 10 with MAMP PRO. Copy the version php.ini file to the folder that has the php.exe. In my case, I copied MAMP/conf/php7.2.1/php.ini file to MAMP/bin/php7.2.1/ folder.

Restarted MAMP PRO 4.

Ran the command line, replacing some-dir with my new Drupal 8 project.

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

**2024 update**: Check if you have enabled "**Make this version available on command line**" option in View -> PHP[image]